# Switch route with NetworkManager connectivity check

Tags: linux, networking, router, centos, networkmanager

I'm having a hard time getting the network manager connectivity check to work.

The goal is to have a failover gateway, and switch between them by increasing the metric on the offline one.

To test this i have one gateway working (`192.168.0.1 metric 200`) and the other (`192.168.0.250 metric 100`) dropping packages from my server.

According to everything i've been reading, it should increase `192.168.0.250 metric` to `20100`, forcing the packages to go through the other gateway.

But it looks like network manager is ignoring the `[connectivity]` config file. Nothing happens.

Changing `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` doesn't help at all.

So, about my config:

**system**:

```
:~# hostnamectl

Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
          Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
    Architecture: x86-64


:~# rpmquery NetworkManager

NetworkManager-1.12.0-10.el7_6.x86_64
```

**enabled connectivity check**:

```
:~# cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/connectivity.conf

[connectivity]

interval=60
response=OK
uri=https://fedoraproject.org/static/hotspot.txt
```

**interface config**:

```
:~# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160

BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
DEVICE=ens160
NAME=ens160
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
PEERNTP=yes
RES_OPTIONS=timeout:1
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
UUID=5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03

IPADDR=192.168.0.18
PREFIX=22

GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
METRIC=200


:~# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens160

default        via 192.168.0.250 metric 100
default        via 192.168.0.1   metric 200
10.0.0.0/8     via 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1
```

**routes**:

:~# ip route

```
default        via 192.168.0.250 dev ens160 metric 100
default        via 192.168.0.1   dev ens160 metric 200
10.0.0.0/8     via 192.168.0.1   dev ens160
192.168.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1   dev ens160
192.168.28.0/22 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.18
169.254.0.0/16  dev ens160 scope link metric 1002
```